# How to merge values from empty rows using Ruby collection functions?

Tags: ruby, select, collections, filter

I have a collection:

```
a = [[1, "a"], [nil, "b"], [nil, "c"], [2, "a"], [nil, "b"]]

[[1, "a"], 
 [nil, "b"], 
 [nil, "c"], 
 [2, "a"], 
 [nil, "b"]]
```

and I would like to get:

```
[[1, "abc"],   
 [2, "ab"]]
```

What is a proper way to achieve this in Ruby? How can do this effectively using ruby built-in collection functions?

Comment: This appears to be a pure-Ruby question, in which case there should not be a Rails tag. Note that some readers filter out questions having certain tags, so you should not include tags that are unnecessarily. Here I would just have a  single tag: "Ruby".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a
.slice_before{|k, _| k}
.map{|a| [a.first.first, a.map(&:last).join]}
# => [[1, "abc"], [2, "ab"]]
```

or

```
a
.slice_before{|k, _| k}
.map{|a| a = a.dup; [a.first.shift, a.join]}
# => [[1, "abc"], [2, "ab"]]
```

Comment: You just miss `]` after `a.map(&:last).join` ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
 input = [[1, "a"], [nil, "b"], [nil, "c"], [2, "a"], [nil, "b"]]
 input.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), acc|
   acc[k] = "" if k
   acc.values.last << v
 end.to_a
 #⇒ [[1, "abc"], [2, "ab"]]
```

Comment: `input.each_with_object({})` returns `{1=>"abc", 2=>"ab"}` just miss `.to_a` ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
a.slice_before(&:first).map do |arr|
  f, *rest = arr.flatten
  [f, rest.join]
end
  #=> [[1, "abc"], [2, "ab"]]
```

See [Enumerable#slice_before](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before), [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) and [Array#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-join). Regarding `join`, `nil` is converted to a string using [NilClass#to_s](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/NilClass.html#method-i-to_s).

The steps are as follows:

```
enum = a.slice_before(&:first)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007fc6eb207858>:each>
```

This is equivalent to

```
enum = a.slice_before { |k,_| k }
```

This enumerator will generate two values which will be passed to the block:

```
enum.next
  #=> [[1, "a"], [nil, "b"], [nil, "c"]]
```

and then

```
enum.next
  #=> [[2, "a"], [nil, "b"]]
```

Note

```
enum.next
  #=> StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```

Before continuing let me reset the enumerator to the beginning with [Enumerator#rewind](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-rewind).

```
enum.rewind
```

The first value of `enum` is generated and passed to the block, captured by the block variable `arr`.

```
arr = enum.next
  #=> [[1, "a"], [nil, "b"], [nil, "c"]]
```

and the block calculations are performed.

```
b = arr.flatten
  #=> [1, "a", nil, "b", nil, "c"]
f, *rest = b
  #=> [1, "a", nil, "b", nil, "c"]
f #=> 1 
rest
  #=> ["a", nil, "b", nil, "c"] 
s = rest.join
  #=> "abc" 
[f, s]
  #=> [1, "abc"]
```

The second value of `enum` is then generated and passed to the block, and the block calculations are performed.

```
arr = enum.next
  #=> [[2, "a"], [nil, "b"]] 
b = arr.flatten
  #=> [2, "a", nil, "b"] 
f, *rest = b
  #=> [2, "a", nil, "b"]
f #=> 2
rest
  #=> ["a", nil, "b"] 
s = rest.join
  #=> "ab" 
[f, s]
  #=> [2, "ab"]
```